# How is possible that a not installed application still runs in Linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu-14.04, ros

I am working with this software (`rtabmap` in Ubuntu 14.04 with ROS Indigo) and I was having some trouble with the installation. So I decided to remove eveything and uninstall it:

```
apt-get remove rtabmap
apt-get remove ros-indigo-rtabmap
cd rtabmap/build
make uninstall
```

And late I have removed the whole `rtabmap` folder.

So now I just run in the console `rtabmap` and it initiates, it even shows me other options like `rtabmap-camera`.
My question is, how is this even possible? And how can I locate the damm package in order to remove it?

Note: `dpkg` does not find it in any way.

Comment: Try `apt-cache search rtabmap`. You probably miss to remove `ros-indigo-rtabmap-ros`.

Comment: Already did it but still. Actually my problem is that i cannot install with catkin_make rtabmap_ros (gives some make errors about some missing attributes of a type). So i think that catkin_make is trying to link rtabmap_ros with not the good rtabmap but with this one so that's why it is giving errors since i had a different version installed previously (master-kinectic)

Comment: `which rtabmap` will tell you the location of the file. This should help you to understand where it comes from and why it still is there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So actually I found the answer myself. It turned out that the binary files of rtabmap where written in /usr/local/bin and there were 2 versions of rtabmap. This way the make was taking the incorrect version and was giving me weird errors.
I just removed the binary files and reinstall over eveything again and now it works.
Cheers